# is using while for this ok?

Tags: c#

```
        while(player.CloseMenu(menuType))
        {
        }
```

`player.CloseMenu(menuType)` will close one menu of the chosen type, or return false if there are none left of that type.

is it ok to use an empty loop like this to close all the menus of a given type?

Comment: It seems a little unconventional.

Comment: yeah that's exactly my point. what else could I do instead without being able to touch the function's body?

Comment: What kind of Framework are you using?

Comment: It seems weird and returning a false seems very out of place from the method name `CloseMenu`. From a glance how can other developers (including yourself in 3 weeks!) know that that method returns a boolean?

Comment: Is there another way to get a list of all open menus and then loop through that list closing them?  That would seem like a less weird way about doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expand on all of these answers and create a method called `CloseAllMenus(MenuType menuType)`. Then you can put whatever kind of ugly implementation in there, and it will be obvious what it is doing when you call it. Your current code doesn't explain what exactly is happening unless you already know that there can be multiple menus of a particular type open, and that this call will only close one of them.

Comment: well actually this is in an extension method for player, `void CloseAllMenues(this Player player, Type menuType)`

Comment: @Nico That changes things a little. If this is the only thing in the function, I would say that you could probably just add a comment to it like `// CloseMenu returns false when it could not find a menu of that type to close` and that would be fine

Answer (score 3):

Be careful when coming up with clever ways of doing things in code.  It may save a few keystrokes in the short run, but someday someone else may look at this code and wonder:

- What is this even doing?
- Ok, I see what it's doing, but why was it done this way?
- Is there a compelling reason for this, and should I avoid it so as to not break something else?

Keep in mind, that someone else may very well be you in several months after you've forgotten the details of this code.

Saving a few lines of code isn't really a big deal.  Anything that has to be written only once is a finite amount of work.  Anything that sows confusion in support going forward produces an unknown and less finite amount of work.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with more self documentation in case other people need to read it.

The problem is that you have to infer from the fact that the invocation is inferred as a bool to understand.

Maybe if you named it player.IsMoreAfterClose().

or

```
while(true)
{
   bool b = player.CloseMenu(menuType);
   if(!b) break;
}
```

or

```
bool b = true;
while(b)
{
  b = player.CloseMenu(menuType);
}
```

Comment: while(true){ /* blah */ break; } is bad form - what might be better is while(player.HasMenusOpen(menuType)){ player.CloseMenu(menuType); } - here the breaking condition is where it should be

Comment: imho, i don't agree its bad form in a loop (whos body has a relatively low line count). the combination of 'while(true)' and 'break' form a (to me) clear picture of 'heres what happens' and 'heres what makes it stop'.

Answer (score 1):

It'll work, obviously, but it makes the code a little hard to read/maintain.  You might be better of with the loop condition being a check for any open menus, with the body of the loop closing one.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to do that as it means `do something until certain condition is met`. But it's better to incorporate that in the `CloseMenu` function so that you don't have to repeat this instruction many times and in fact it's a variation of closing menu where you want to close all menus. You can add a boolean argument to the function to indicate if you want to close all menus.

```
bool CloseMenu(type, closeAll){
   if(closeAll)
      while(exists(type))
      { close...
   else
      if(exists(type)
      { close...
}
```

Comment: Boolean arguments are not intuitive. It is hard to understand what method is doing, e.g. the difference between CloseMenu('type', false) and CloseMenu('type', true) is not obvious. I would suggest adding two different public methods with meaningful names, like CloseAllMenus.

Comment: It's obvious if you read the API (even function signature suffice, as a (properly chosen) argument name can indicate it's purpose), which is what a developer should do.

Comment: It is much better if the code is easy to understand without reading the API. Why developer should waste time reading the API? :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the "right" thing to do is invert from While/Close with no body to For/Open with the body doing the Close operation.

```
foreach(var menu in player.OpenMenus)
  menu.Close();
```

or:

```
player.OpenMenus.ForEach(c => c.Close());
```